# Failure reading sector 0x... From hd0

Tags: kernel, grub2, hard-disk, grub

I recently installed Manjaro, everything went great (I have installed OS lots of times without any problems), but this time, my computer won't boot for some reasons. It shows me this and I can't type anything..

[image: The picture when I boot]

It already occured 4-5 times, I usually ragequit and go to sleep when it happens, and when I wake up, it boots normally..

Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Thank you very much

Edit: I manage to boot, if that can help to make commands..

Comment: Looks like a dying disk

Comment: Boot using System Rescue, run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` post the result.

Comment: @roaima A physically dying disk, or could it be fixed?

Comment: Post the result of the `smartctl` and we'll be able to answer that